# Dyamically Change DefaultButton present inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

How to dynamically Change DefaultButton Property of the Form from UserControl present in a page.Page is loaded into a master page contains Update Panel.

When Try to change the Default button in  onload event of the UserControl, It is not changing.

```
if(lastpage)
{
this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSave.UniqueID;
}
else
{
this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnNext.UniqueID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote from msdn:

> The following scenarios for setting
>   the default postback button on a page
>   are not supported during asynchronous
>   postbacks:
>
> ```
> * Changing the DefaultButton programmatically during an asynchronous post back.
> ```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx

Could you not postback the state of the form and then work out which action to take rather than passing this information based on which button was clicked?